# Build real time notification using comet in php

Tags: push-notification, comet

I want to build real time notification system just like facebook and google+. I know they are using comet and ajax push technology for that.I have found the tutorial http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start from this link i just want to know that how can i implement Comet with iframe technique(you can found this on above link) using mysql database and how i can i identify the user to whom i push the data.

Thank You.